# Font face not working in mozilla and chrome

Tags: css, font-face

I have a problem with font-face in mozilla browser and chrome.
Actually, I use font-face and its working fine, but this is a first time i use font-face with font : Penshurst and its not working. When i using another font is working fine.

This is my font-face code :

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Penshurst;
    src:url("../../plugin/font/penshurst.ttf"),url("../../plugin/font/penshurst.eot");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Century Regular;
    src:url("../../plugin/font/century gothic regular.ttf"),url("../../plugin/font/century gothic regular.eot");
}
```

For font face with font: Century Regular, it's working fine, but for Penshurst its not working.

Any suggestion for this problem?
Thx

Comment: This should work. Are you referencing it properly from elements? Can you paste the CSS of elements that use this font? Also, first check the TTF file elsewhere, like on your Desktop in MS Word for example, by installing it there.

Comment: Try to add appropriate `format()` after each `url()`.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I'm already try to use format after tag url(), but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try IE or Opera. If the won't display it, you have a problem with font files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct format:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Penshurst';
    src: url('../../plugin/font/penshurst.eot');
    src: url('../../plugin/font/penshurst.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')? /* if needed for IE */,
         url('../../plugin/font/penshurst.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also...
you might need this:

```
     `url('../../plugin/font/penshurst.woff') format('woff'),`
```

...you might have to convert to get this...(see my link on my comment below)

Make sure your server IIS has MIME Type for .eot/.otf/.ttf/.woff so that way you can preview them locally or online(server)...and lastly even though you can see Century Regular doesn't mean that Penshurst in your server/localhost

:)

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I try another font-family and it works, but for penshurst font, nothing. Or maybe mozilla and chrome doesn't support this font maybe? Any suggestion?

Comment: ok try converting it here so you can also have WOFF file:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator